# extjs 4 form still has record set after form.reset();

Tags: extjs

I have a grid bound to a form the forms submit action is to update the loaded record if there is one and add a new record if its a blank form.  but if I select a record first and then call

```
myGrid.getSelectionModel().deselectAll();
myform.getForm().reset();
```

to clear the form so I can add a new record it overwrites the previously selected record with an update.

```
record = myform.getRecord();
if(record){
record.set(values);
}
```

shouldn't myform.getRecord(); be null after a reset?  how do I clear the record selection?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reset Form Record Not Clearing Values - ExtJS 4.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18988727/reset-form-record-not-clearing-values-extjs-4-2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, no, it shouldn't and you don't have legal approaches to clear the record after the first time you load anything via [`loadRecord`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-loadRecord).
Although, you could still do `myform.getForm()._record = null` assignment, I would strongly object against that, as it may break some internal functionality by ExtJS.

Here is an extract from ExtJS [API](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api):

> getRecord() : Ext.data.Model
>   Returns the last Ext.data.Model instance
>   that was loaded via loadRecord

And it does exactly that, returns the last record loaded via [`loadRecord`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-loadRecord).

Here are some sources:

```
getRecord: function() {
    return this._record;
},

loadRecord: function(record) {
    this._record = record;
    return this.setValues(record.data);
},
```

Actually, those are the only methods of [`Ext.form.Basic`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic) (an instance of which is returned by [`getForm()`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-getForm)) dealing with `this._record` field.

As for reset

```
reset: function() {
    var me = this;
    me.batchLayouts(function() {
        me.getFields().each(function(f) {
            f.reset();
        });
    });
    return me;
},
```

As you could see, reset has nothing to do with the record returned by [`getRecord()`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-getRecord), it's just resetting field values.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!  I've added a hidden field for the recordID instead and Ill verify what type of submit I have by whether or not the id field is set.

Comment: This is no longer valid. Look at the answers of question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18988727/reset-form-record-not-clearing-values-extjs-4-2

Answer (score 3):

For anyone interested, you can override the default form panel to add functionality to clear form fields. Add the following to your code:

```
     Ext.override(Ext.form.Panel, {
         clearForm:function(){
             Ext.each(this.getForm().getFields().items, function(field){
                    field.setValue('');
             });
         }
    });
```

You can then clear a form using:

`myForm.clearForm()`

Where `myForm` is your form panel.

Answer (score 3):

This is what you looking for:

```
form.getForm().reset(true);
```

True to unbind any record set by loadRecord.

See [Ext.form.Basic.reset()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-reset) syntax

Comment: not if you are also using trackResetOnLoad: true in order to keep track of validity changes.

Answer (score 0):

I find this question because I have a similar scenario but slightly different:

- ExtJS 4.1.1
- TreePanel

In ExtJS 4.1 in sync() method you can use an options object in which you can define a callback, success and failure functions. Since I'm sure I'm only synchronozing just one record, I loaded the returned record:

```
me.getHelpItemsStore().sync({
    success: function(batch) {
        // We expect single operation so...
        var record = batch.operations[0].getRecords()[0];
        form.loadRecord(record);
    }
});
```

Little late but hope helps you.